# How do I write to multiple fields of a structured array?

Tags: arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have an nd-array with names fields as below.  I'm trying to assign values to multiple fields at once, but it seems to have no effect at all.  See the example below:

```
In [380]: A = numpy.zeros(dtype=[("A", "f8"), ("B", "f8"), ("C", "f8")], shape=(5,))                                                                                                                 

In [381]: A[["A", "B", "C"]][0] = (2, 3, 4)
```

I would expect that now, these values are assigned to `A`, but in fact, the array is still all-zero:

```
In [382]: A[0]
Out[382]: (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

When I index the other way around, I get an `IndexError`; (`A[0]["A"]` works, but `A[0][["A", "B", "C"]]` is `IndexError`:

```
In [383]: A[0][["A", "B", "C"]] = (2, 3, 4)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-383-9b5cca19867a> in <module>()
----> 1 A[0][["A", "B", "C"]] = (2, 3, 4)

IndexError: invalid index
```

Why does `A[fieldnames][0] = values` not assign anything?  Why does `A[0][fieldnames]` fail with an `IndexError`?  How can I write multiple values at once to a structured array (apart from looping explicitly)?

Comment: Presumably you mean you want to write to multiple _but not all_ fields?  Because to do what you're showing, you can just use `A[0] = 2, 3, 4`

Comment: @askewchan Right, in the current simplified example that works, but that works only if (1) I write to all fields (2) my values come in the same order as the fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to set all three fields, as you show in your example, you can simply just select the first entry:

```
A[0] = 2, 3, 4
```

In the other case (like `A[['A','B']][0] = 2, 3`) this might help you understand a little:

```
FutureWarning: Numpy has detected that you (may be) writing to an array returned
by numpy.diagonal or by selecting multiple fields in a record
array. This code will likely break in a future numpy release --
see numpy.diagonal or arrays.indexing reference docs for details.
The quick fix is to make an explicit copy (e.g., do
arr.diagonal().copy() or arr[['f0','f1']].copy()).
```

This will probably be made easier in future versions of numpy, because indexing with several fields will soon return a view:

> [Record Access](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#record-access)
>
> If the [ndarray](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html#numpy.ndarray) object is a record array, i.e. its data type is a
>   record data type, the fields of the array can be accessed by indexing
>   the array with strings, dictionary-like.
>
> Indexing `x['field-name']` returns a new [*view*](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/glossary.html#term-view) to the array, which is of
>   the same shape as *x* (except when the field is a sub-array) but of data
>   type `x.dtype['field-name']` and contains only the part of the data in
>   the specified field. Also record array scalars can be “indexed” this
>   way.
>
> Indexing into a record array can also be done with a list of field
>   names, e.g. `x[['field-name1','field-name2']]`. Currently this returns a
>   new array containing a copy of the values in the fields specified in
>   the list. As of NumPy 1.7, returning a copy is being deprecated in
>   favor of returning a view. A copy will continue to be returned for
>   now, but a `FutureWarning` will be issued when writing to the copy. If
>   you depend on the current behavior, then we suggest copying the
>   returned array explicitly, i.e. use
>   `x[[‘field-name1’,’field-name2’]].copy()`. This will work with both past
>   and future versions of NumPy.

Answer (score 0):

- `A[fieldnames][0] = values` assigns nothing because you are assigning the value to a copy of the array, returned by `A[fieldnames]`.
- `A[0][["A", "B", "C"]]` fails because as the message says `["A", "B", "C"]` is an invalid index. You want to use `A[0]=2,3,4`.

Comment: You can avoid the invalid index by slicing: `A[:1][["A", "B", "C"]]` but you still can't assign to that slice.

Comment: right, though that would create a copy of the slice in any case. You can again use `A[:1]=2,3,4`.